# Helper function returning array instead of fixNum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I defined a function in application helper in Rails which is supposed to return the id of a particular model. But, instead the function returns an array with a single hash-like element.

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def singleton(documents) #this function works perfectly
    count = 0

    documents.each do |document|
      if ((document.extension == 'jpg') || (document.extension == 'jpeg') || (document.extension == 'png') || (document.extension == 'gif') || (document.extension == 'bmp'))
        count += 1
      end
    end

    return count
  end

  def getbanner(course) #this function is returning array some problem
    picid = -99
    storeval = singleton(course.documents)

    if (storeval == 0)
      picid = -99
    elsif (storeval == 1)
      course.documents.each do |document|
        if ((document.extension == 'jpg') || (document.extension == 'jpeg') || (document.extension == 'png') || (document.extension == 'gif') || (document.extension == 'bmp'))
          picid = document.id
        end
      end
    elsif (storeval > 1)
      course.documents.each do |document|
        if ((document.extension == 'jpg') || (document.extension == 'jpeg') || (document.extension == 'png') || (document.extension == 'gif') || (document.extension == 'bmp'))
          picid = document.id
          return picid
        end
        #return picid
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

I am invoking the function inside a block in the erb template like this:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <% banndocid = getbanner(course) %>
  <% docofbanner = course.documents.find(banndocid) %>
  <!--- START OF CARD -->
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to( course_path(course) ) do %>
      <div class="container card">
        <div class="row" style="display:flex;align-items: center;">
          <div class="col-xs-4 ">
            <%= image_tag( docofbanner.file.url, class: "img img-responsive pull-left center-block", style: "margin-top:1em;margin-bottom:1em;", alt: "icon" ) %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="row"><h2><%= course.name %></h2></div>
            <div class="row"><p><%= course.summary %></p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

The result of the function comes as:

```
Document id: 8, name: "dfgjk", extension: "png", created_at: "2016-01-28 09:05:42", updated_at: "2016-01-28 09:05:42", file: "Screenshot_from_2015-11-22_23-12-36.png", course_id: 3
```

I want this function to return a number.

Comment: You only specify "return picid" in the third if block. What is being returned in the first two if blocks?

Comment: FWIW `if ((document.extension == 'jpg') || (document.extension == 'jpeg') || ...)` is better expressed as `if document.extension == 'jpg' || document.extension == 'jpeg' || ...`, which is better expressed as `if %w[ jpg jpeg png gif bmp ].include?(document.extension)` or, better still, `if document.extension =~ /^(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return a number in most cases.

If `storeval == 1` you'll return the results of the `each`. Same if it isn't an image file and `storeval > 1`. By the way, if it can't be < 0, and isn't 0, and isn't 1, you can bet it's greater than 1. That code deserves a thorough cleaning.

Boo for repeated image identification code, which should be a method. I'd also probably just use an array and see if it includes the extension.

I can't tell if you are really running different code for == 1 and > 1, but roughly:

```
def getbanner(course) #this function is returning array some problem
  storeval = singleton(course.documents)

  if storeval >= 1
    course.documents.each do |document|
      return document.id if image?(document)
    end
  end

  return -99
end
```